# Icon doesn't change on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, icons

**The problem**

Even though i changed the icon on android studio , and shows me the correct icon in the device preview, when i run the emulator an old icon appears.

**Evidence**

Icon properly changed in preview.

[image]

Choosing icon from resources.

[image]

**Outcome**

[image]

Comment: Do you have any other icon on other drawable folder with the same name?

Answer (score 1):

@user2651401 : I think duplicate entry happen . Please fix the duplicate drawable issue . After that, 
**`Build > Clean Project`** Then `Gradle &Restart Project` .